# Add drawer toggle button in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, android-compose-appbar

I want to add the hamburger icon to the Appbar and open/close drawer using the icon.

[image]

How would I achieve this?

```
Scaffold(
    drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(topRight = 10.dp, bottomRight = 10.dp),
    drawerElevation = 5.dp,
    drawerContent = {
      // Drawer
    },
    topBar = {
      TopAppBar(
        navigationIcon = {
          Icon(
            Icons.Default.Menu,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
              // Open drawer => How?
            })
          )
        },

        modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .clip(RoundedCornerShape(bottomLeft = 10.dp, bottomRight = 10.dp)),
        title = { Text(text = "Hello") }
      )
    },
  ) {}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use **`rememberScaffoldState()`** to modify drawer state.

1. create a variable:

```
val state = rememberScaffoldState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope() // in 1.0.0-beta `open()` and `close` are suspend functions
```

2. Pass the state to `Scaffold`

```
Scaffold(
   scaffoldState = state,
   // ...
)
```

3. Use `state.drawerState.open()` or `state.drawerState.close()` in an `onClick` to open/close the drawer.
4. Create an Icon for `navigationIcon` in `TopAppBar`:

```
val state = rememberScaffoldState()
Scaffold(
  scaffoldState = state,
  topBar = {
    TopAppBar(
      title = { Text(text = "AppBar") },
      navigationIcon = {
        Icon(
          Icons.Default.Menu,
          modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
            scope.launch { if(it.isClosed) it.open() else it.close() }
          })
        )
      }
    )
  },
  drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(topRight = 10.dp, bottomRight = 10.dp),
  drawerContent = {
    Text(text = "Drawer")
  }
) {
   // Scaffold body
}
```

Comment: What does `rememberScaffoldState` does?

Comment: It's an internal state in the Scaffold composable. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#rememberscaffoldstate)

Comment: what is "it"???

Comment: Been a long time. But I think `state.drawerState`

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = { Text("Drawer content") },
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
           modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 8.dp, bottomEnd = 8.dp))
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu,"")
            }
        }
    },
    content = {
        //bodyContent()
    })
```

[image]